# How to define $f$ so that $\mathbb{R}P^n \cong \mathbb{R}P^{n-1} ~ \cup_f D^n$

Tags: general-topology, projective-space

I would like to show that $S^n / \{ v \sim -v \}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1} ~\cup_f D^n$, where $D^n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : |x| \leq 1\}$. I have already shown this for $n=2$.

I should define $f$. However, this is where my difficulty lies: when $n=2$, $\mathbb{R}P^{n-1} \cong S^1$, and it is easy to define $f: \partial D^2 \to \mathbb{R}P^1$ as the map taking $z$ to $z^2$ (where we consider $\partial D^2$ and $\mathbb{R}P^1 \cong S^1$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{C}$.) This attaching map identifies three points in $\partial D^2, \mathbb{R}P^1$ with a single point in their adjunction space; namely, $x \in \partial D^2$ with $-x$, along with a pair of antipodal points in $\mathbb{R}P^1$ (how would I word that rigorously?)

What I would like to know is, how can I define $f:\partial D^n \to \mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ when $n>2$? When $n=2$, I describe $f$ as a map which 'doubles the angle' of a point of $\partial D^2$, but this does not generalize well to higher $n$.

Comment: It might help to view $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$ as the quotient of $S^{n-1}$ by the anitpodal map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may help to view $\mathbb{RP}^{n-1}$ as the quotient of $S^{n-1}$ by the antipodal map. Along with the identification $\partial D^n = S^{n-1}$, the attaching map is just the 'obvious' map $x \mapsto [x]$. This is expanded upon in Example 2.42 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology, where he uses this to compute the (cellular) homology of $\mathbb{RP}^n$.